# How to pass value into GET method in Android Studio?

Tags: java, php, android, http-get

In have these data in my database, and some of the users have same DEPT value. My goal is when user login into page (i.e A1) is loggedin . It only display all the user that have the **same dept value only which is A1,B1,E1**.

```
---------------------------
| id   | user_id | dept   |
---------------------------
| 1    | A1      | ITD    | 
| 2    | B1      | ITD    |
| 3    | C1      | FAD    |
| 4    | D1      | PNC    |
| 5    | E1      | ITD    |
| 6    | F1      | PSSB   |
```

But the problem is **my user_id and dept output data is in JAVA Android Studio**.

Plus, in this case **request.GET** is applied instead of POST.

**JAVA File**

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static final String dept = "DEPT";
    public static final String user_id   = "ID";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        final String dept   = (String) extras.get("DEPT");
        final String user_id     = (String) extras.get("USERID");
        getData();
    }

    private void getData(){
        String url = "https://www.aaa.com/test.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                JSONObject j = null;
                try{
                    j       = new JSONObject(response);
                    result  = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                    getStaffs(result);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Test.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Is it possible or am i doing it the wrong way ?

And also my PHP file as below.

**PHP file**

```
<?php
    $connect      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "database");
    global $connect;   
    if(isset($_GET['dept']))
    {
        $dept = $_GET['dept'];
        $sql        = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE dept='$dept'";
        $get        = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $result     = array();
            while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
                array_push($result, array(
                        'user_id' => $row['user_id'],
                        'dept'     => $row['dept']
                    ));
            }
        echo json_encode(array('result' => $result));
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
?>
```

**Config.class**

```
public class Config {
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY        = "result";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use Volley or Retrofit2 its quit easy to use these libraries

Comment: yup. my current code is using volley . . i'm using string request

Comment: use POST method

Comment: But i want to display the data without click or post something to php . .